# How to get a more accurate gps location?

Tags: android, listview, history

I have an app that will get the users gps location. The problem is right now it is a bit inaccurate (it shows me in a different building 20-60m off)

here is my code

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                    false);
            LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            try {
                Looper.prepare();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0,
                        loc_listener);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

I believe I should wait at least one second before sending location.getLatitude() and location.getLongitude() Right now the wait time is almost instant but the accuracy is pretty off. I am using my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each location update provided by your GPS chip will have an accuracy value. You should consider throwing away ones that are above a threshold.

However, indoors GPS struggles to get a signal, so accuracy will decrease, if it even manages to get a lock at all!

Comment: This has an example for calculating the best fix provided: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html  And you can return the accuracy of a returned Location object from its `Location.getAccuracy()` function.